# Make POST request with 'requests' module in Python

Tags: python, post, httprequest, python-requests

So I have installed the python 'requests' module, and it is working, but I am having trouble seeing how it all fits together. I've searched online and could not find any practical examples for how this things worked.

So I'm going to give a sample POST request and the answer I'm looking for is that request in Python code. I've looked everywhere and I can't find any direct translation between just a basic POST format and how that looks in Python.

Thanks for the help!

Here's my example POST request:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8
host: https://testsite.com
content-length:207

Blah=content&blah2=content2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass a dictionary to the `data` keyword, using the `.post()` function:

```
data = {'Blah': 'content', 'blah2': 'content2'}
r = requests.post('https://testsite.com/', data=data)
```

See the [More complicated POST requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) section of the Quickstart documentation.

The same post to http://httpbin.org/post:

```
>>> import requests, pprint
>>> data = {'Blah': 'content', 'blah2': 'content2'}
>>> r = requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', data=data)
>>> pprint.pprint(r.json())
{u'args': {},
 u'data': u'',
 u'files': {},
 u'form': {u'Blah': u'content', u'blah2': u'content2'},
 u'headers': {u'Accept': u'*/*',
              u'Accept-Encoding': u'gzip, deflate, compress',
              u'Connection': u'close',
              u'Content-Length': u'27',
              u'Content-Type': u'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
              u'Host': u'httpbin.org',
              u'User-Agent': u'python-requests/2.0.1 CPython/2.7.5 Darwin/11.4.2',
              u'X-Request-Id': u'6df0a100-f193-4272-adf5-3b6bb6a77461'},
 u'json': None,
 u'origin': u'84.92.98.170',
 u'url': u'http://httpbin.org/post'}
>>> r.request.headers
CaseInsensitiveDict({'Content-Length': u'27', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, compress', 'Accept': '*/*', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.0.1 CPython/2.7.5 Darwin/11.4.2'})
```

httpbin.org echoes back the headers that were sent; the `Content-Length` and `Content-Type` headers were set for you by `requests`.

You can always add or override headers with the `headers` parameter:

```
>>> r = requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', data=data,
...     headers={'User-Agent': 'Stack Overflow requests demo'})
>>> pprint.pprint(r.json())
{u'args': {},
 u'data': u'',
 u'files': {},
 u'form': {u'Blah': u'content', u'blah2': u'content2'},
 u'headers': {u'Accept': u'*/*',
              u'Accept-Encoding': u'gzip, deflate, compress',
              u'Connection': u'close',
              u'Content-Length': u'27',
              u'Content-Type': u'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
              u'Host': u'httpbin.org',
              u'User-Agent': u'Stack Overflow requests demo',
              u'X-Request-Id': u'b489f151-e5c2-4f49-ad00-141a0658c54a'},
 u'json': None,
 u'origin': u'84.92.98.170',
 u'url': u'http://httpbin.org/post'}
>>> r.request.headers
CaseInsensitiveDict({'Content-Length': u'27', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, compress', 'Accept': '*/*', 'User-Agent': 'Stack Overflow requests demo'})
```

Comment: but what about the headers?

Comment: @IsaiahTaylor `Content-Type` and `Content-Length` will be automatically set when you pass a dictionary as the data; the host comes from the URL. If you want to pass other headers, you [can add those too](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#custom-headers).

Comment: @IsaiahTaylor: the headers are taken care of *for you* by the `requests` module.

Comment: Thanks guys! This site is a lifesaver.

Comment: How would I edit those preset headers? Does passing it a header argument override all preset headers?

Comment: @IsaiahTaylor: any header in the [`headers` dictionary](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#custom-headers) would override headers `requests` would set automatically.

Comment: @IsaiahTaylor: Please note that generally you won't want to override Content-Length. Doing so can sometimes cause Requests to do unexpected things.

Comment: @Lukasa: Not to mention the server. The value has actual meaning, after all!

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Quite right. And yet, we get bug reports caused by people doing that on a regular basis. ;)